# How to make 2 select statements in one query?

Tags: c#, mysql, database

i got a database table that contains:
Name,X,Y,Z

here's the part i'm selecting some values from the database :

MySqlConnection myConn = new MySqlConnection(myConnection);
            MySqlCommand command = myConn.CreateCommand();
            command.CommandText = "SELECT `Name` , `X`, `Y`, `Z` FROM `gestures`  ";
            MySqlDataReader myReader;

```
        try
        {
            myConn.Open();
            myReader = command.ExecuteReader();
            while (myReader.Read())
            {
                FromDB.Name = myReader[0].ToString();
                MPoint asdd = new MPoint((double)myReader[1], (double)myReader[2], (double)myReader[3]);
                FromDB.FDB.Add(asdd);

            }

            files.Add(FromDB);
        }

        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }

        myConn.Close();
```

what i'm asking for is how to select distinct name instead of selecting the repeated names and selecting all the X,Y,Z points even the repeated ones

i hope i clarified my question

Comment: You should narrow this question down a bit.  What have you tried and where are you having problems?  We're happy to help but we're not going to build out a sample application for you...

Comment: It's not WAMP if you're using C#. WAMP stands for Windows, Apache, MySql, PHP (or less commonly, perl and python).

Comment: Please help verify if my ans is as you expect.

Answer (score 0):

To select all records on a unique column from a MySQL database using C#:

```
    using MySql.Data.MySqlClient; 
    ...
    var connectionString = "<insert connection string here>"; 
    using (var connection = new MySqlConnection(connectionString))
    { 
       connection.Open();

       var query = "select * from gestures group by name";
       var command = new MySqlCommand(query, connection);
       using (var reader = command.ExecuteReader())
       {
          while (reader.Read())
          {
              var name = reader.GetString(0);
              var pointX = reader.GetInt32(1);
              var pointY = reader.GetInt32(2);
              var pointZ = reader.GetInt32(3);

              Console.WriteLine($"{name}: {x},{y},{z}");
          }
       }
     }
```

Edit: [Link](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-net/en/connector-net-programming.html) to MySQL C# documentation.